# "UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:" and then nothing's showing up

Tags: python-3.x, macos, anaconda, miniconda

So I'm trying to install [ubermag](https://ubermag.github.io/installation.html) into a new conda environment on my terminal:

`(ubermag) sarthakhajirnis@dhcp-10-132-234-194 ~ % conda install --channel conda-forge ubermag`

But all I'm getting is:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions
```

And that's it, no information about which package is creating this discrepancy.

I checked the documentation and verified whether the version of python is compatible with ubermag; turns out it is.

One possible reason for this could be that I already had anaconda on my laptop, but I went ahead with installing miniconda. But I'm not sure why this could be the case.

I'm using 13.0.1 (22A400) version of Mac.